# Angular property binding without assignment

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I want to create a reusable component with `@Input() close = false` and in the parent `<my-reusable-component close></my-reusable-component>`.

Like material button with `<button mat-button disabled></button>`.

But i got "type string is not assignable to type boolean..

Any idea ?

Comment: provide us minimum code example of what you've done

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign a boolean to it, by binding it to a boolean

```html
<my-reusable-component [close]="true"></my-reusable-component>
```

Otherwise, you can set the `@Input()` to an optional type (allow `undefined`) and check for not `undefined` to see if it's defined and/or true:

```js
@Input() close: boolean | undefined;


private isClosed() {
  return (this.close !== undefined && this.close !== false) || this.close === true;
}
```

And then you should be able to use it either like:

```html
<my-reusable-component close></my-reusable-component>
```

or:

```html
<my-reusable-component [close]="true"></my-reusable-component>
```

I've made a sample here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lbn6d9?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: You can also use `@Attribute` and `@Optional`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use @Attribute @Optional

```
close:boolean
constructor(@Optional() @Attribute('close') close:string){
   this.close=close!=null;
}
```

Comment: Does that work for components? I thought @Attribute was only for directives. *Edit: yeah, seems it does, I'll +1 here*

Comment: @Jcl, really if we think in a "Input" that don't change we should use "Attribute" instead of "Input", e.g. a mask of an input or an alert of type warning or...

Comment: yes, I'd use it like that also, I just thought `@Attribute` only worked on directives, not on components, but I was wrong :-)

Comment: I never see @Attribute.. thanks do the job !